# IWICBitmapScaler doesn't work for 96bppRGBFloat format?

Tags: windows, components, imaging, wic

I encountered a probem when I was using the WIC lib. And I found that I can't scale R32G32B32 images using IWICBitmapScaler... The code example shows below:

```
{
    IWICImagingFactory* m_pWICFactory;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    // Initialize COM
    hr = CoInitialize(nullptr);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    // Initialize Factory
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        __uuidof(IWICImagingFactory), (void**)&m_pWICFactory);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    // 4x4 R32G32B32 image
    XMFLOAT3 srcImg[] = { XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1),
        XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1),
        XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), 
        XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), XMFLOAT3(1, 1, 1), };

    // 2x2 R32G32B32 image
    XMFLOAT3 dstImg[4];

    CComPtr<IWICBitmap> pSrcBitmap;
    hr = m_pWICFactory->CreateBitmapFromMemory(4, 4, GUID_WICPixelFormat96bppRGBFloat, 4 * sizeof(XMFLOAT3),
        4 * sizeof(XMFLOAT3)* 4, (BYTE*)srcImg, &pSrcBitmap);

    IWICBitmapSource *pSrcBitmapSource = pSrcBitmap.p;

    // scale to 2x2
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapScaler> pScaler;
    hr = m_pWICFactory->CreateBitmapScaler(&pScaler);
    hr = pScaler->Initialize(pSrcBitmapSource, 2, 2, WICBitmapInterpolationModeFant);
    pSrcBitmapSource = pScaler.p;

    // copy back
    WICRect rect = { 0, 0, 2, 2 };
    hr = pSrcBitmapSource->CopyPixels(&rect, 2 * sizeof(XMFLOAT3), 2 * sizeof(XMFLOAT3)* 2, (BYTE*)dstImg);

}
```

And I just get -1.#QNAN000 in the dstImg buffer :(
I'm not sure whether I did something wrong, or the IWICBitmapScaler just don't support such format?

Another ploblem is that when I use IWICFormatConverter to convert R32G32B32A32 (i.e. 128bppRGBFloat) images to R32Gray (i.e.32bppGrayFloat)format, it always clamp the value to [0, 1], is this a desired behavior? (Why???)

(My platform: Win 8.1 64bit + VS2013)

Comment: I repro, Win81 as well.  I see no flaw, better stay away from the pixel format for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly assuming that the `IWICBitmapScaler` always returns the data in the same pixel format as it's input. It does not. You have to call `GetPixelFormat` to find out how the result is going to be formatted. Also, when working with a COM API you *must* be checking the HRESULT for every call that returns one to catch problems.

```
CComPtr<IWICBitmapScaler> pScaler;
hr = m_pWICFactory->CreateBitmapScaler(&pScaler);
if ( FAILED(hr) )
    ...
hr = pScaler->Initialize(pSrcBitmapSource, 2, 2, ICBitmapInterpolationModeFant);
if ( FAILED(hr) )
    ...
pSrcBitmapSource = pScaler.p;

WICPixelFormatGUID pfScaler;
hr = scaler->GetPixelFormat( &pfScaler );
if ( FAILED(hr) )
    ...

// In many cases, pfScaler will not be the same GUID as your pSrcBItmapSource.
```

You should take a look at [DirctXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926) for extensive examples of using WIC.